# Find n number of empty adjacent positions in a String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm

I am designing a program that will store a given amount of strings side by side in a partially filled array.
I am having difficulties creating an algorithm that does the following:

1. Receives a string array and an `int` value indicating how many empty adjacent spots in the array are required.
2. Searches through the array to find the different blocks of empty spots of that size.
3. Randomly picks the starting index of one of these empty blocks
4. Returns the value in (3) - `int`

Here is an example of how it is supposed to work.
Given  `String []arr = {"greg", null, null, "adam", null, "phil",null, null };` if i intend to find a block of two empty seats:
`public static int getIndex(arr, 2) {...}` should return either position `arr[1]` or `arr[6]`

please how do i solve this problem?

Comment: Loop through the array and, when you find an empty slot, start another loop starting there to check if the "run" of empty slots is what you need. If so, return the starting index. Note this is O(n^2) and I don't know if a better solution exists. I'd rather not write the code for you. That isn't what we do.

Comment: I think it can be done in `O(n)` by working out the groups of `null`s (say, keep a list of start index & length) and then working out from there what indexes start an appropriate length block (this is saved into an array of indexes). Finally, choose randomly from this array.

Comment: @shapiroyaacov how? please elaborate

Comment: @Paul has it spot on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved pretty simple:

```
List<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<>();

int len = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
    if(s == null)
        len++;
    else
        len = 0;

    if(len >= min_len)
        pos.add(i - min_len + 1);

return pos.get(new Random().nextInt(pos.size()));
```

Comment: i tested it with the array i posted in the question and it keeps returning either index 0 or 5. please test

Comment: i added one to the return value and it works fine. thanks

Comment: @i_use_the_internet oh, right, sry. I had a little logic mistake in my thoughts. i'll correct that

Comment: so what if there is an instance where there are no blocks of 'n' nulls. say we run out of blocks of two nulls, how do i modify the code not to cause an exception by making the default return value -1?

Comment: @i_use_the_internet i thought it was a constraint that the input hat atleast one block of `n` nulls. Just add a condition at the end: `return (pos.isEmpty() ? -1 : pos.get(...));`